# Firefox + IE10. How to force inline-block to respect full width of its inner float+overflow:hidden divs?

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-10

**EDITED on 30.04.13: IE10 seems to got rid of described behavior, and the only browser where we can watch this behavior now is Firefox**

I want one div `(.side)` to be floated right inside inline-block `(.wrap)`, and I want another div `(.content)` to contain long non-wrapping string with text-overflow: ellipsis in case of overflow. Also `.wrap` should not be wider than its container, so it has max-width: 100%.

When width of content in `.content` combined with width of `.side` is wide enough to be wider than container of a `.wrap` - content in `.content` should overflow it.

And when width of content in `.content` combined with width of `.side` is less than width of container of a `.wrap` - then there should be no overflow in `.content`, `.wrap` just should take width of `.content` and `.side` combined. Seems so, but not in Firefox and IE10. In this two browsers width of `.wrap` is as wide as the widest inner div. But I expected that `.wrap` will respect width of both `.side` and `.content`.

You can see this behavior here: http://jsbin.com/evamik/1/ , just make browser window wide enough and you will see that there is text-overflow in lime-colored div `(.content)`. If you will turn off overflow:hidden on `.content` you will see, that width of a `.wrap` equal to width of a `.content`, and width of `.side` is ignored.

So how to force `.wrap` to respect width of both `.side` and `.content`?

HTML:

```
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="side">
       side
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       nonwrappnonwrappingnonwrappingnonwrappingnonwrapping
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  background: lime;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.side {
  float: right;
  background: orange;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}  
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Example url: http://jsbin.com/evamik/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by this question. The jsbin example seems to have the desired behavior in IE10 on Windows 7. (That is, the `.content` div uses ellipsis when the window is too narrow to show the full line, and `.side` always displays correctly as floated right, with the `.wrap` parent div fitting the child divs if the window allows all text to display, and having 100% width when the window is narrow enough to cause text overflow.)

Turning off `overflow:hidden;` on the `.content` div causes ugly behavior because without it, `text-overflow:ellipsis;` has no effect, but `white-space:no-wrap;` is forcing the text to stay on one unbroken line.

Note that `text-overflow:ellipsis;` ONLY works when also using `white-space:no-wrap;` and `overflow:hidden;`. This means you can't use ellipsis for multi-line text. See [MDN CSS reference for text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow).

If you want to ensure text wrapping instead of using a single line with ellipsis, you can remove `white-space:no-wrap;` and `overflow:hidden;` and add instead `word-wrap:break-word;`, which will break long words to fit narrow spaces. See [MDN CSS reference for word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: In IE10 (Win 8) - yep, this bug is already gone. But it still exists in the latest Firefox (20.0.1 - Win 7, 20.0 - Mac). After you`ll check jsbin example there - I guess my question should become clear.